When I add a redirect to /checkout page using middleware the sign out button breaks
When I add a redirect to /checkout page using middleware, the sign out button breaks.
This is my middleware:
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt";

// Lista of protected routes.
const protectedRoutes = [
  "/dashboard",
  "/forms",
  "/leads",
  "/settings",
  "/meeting-link",
  "/meetings",
  "/workflows",
];

const isProtectedRoute = (pathname) => {
  const pathSegments = pathname.split("/").filter(Boolean);
  return protectedRoutes.some((protectedPath) => {
    const protectedSegments = protectedPath.split("/").filter(Boolean);
    return protectedSegments.every((seg, index) => seg === pathSegments[index]);
  });
};

export async function middleware(req) {
  const { pathname } = req.nextUrl;
  const token = await getToken({ req, secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET });
  const subscription = token?.subscription;
  console.log({ token });
  const requestHeaders = new Headers(req.headers);
  requestHeaders.set("x-url", req.url);

  // If route protected and !token redirect to login
  if (isProtectedRoute(pathname) && !token) {
    console.log("Ruta protegida: ", pathname);
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/login", req.url));
  }
  // Fix the redirect next.js not serve css
  if (req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/_next")) {
    return NextResponse.next();
  }

  if (subscription?.status === "EXPIRED" && pathname !== "/checkout") {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/checkout", req.url));
  }

modificaciones
  return NextResponse.next({
    headers: requestHeaders,
  });
}

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/:path*"],
};

I'm trying to achieve that when some company subscription trial is expired, redirect them to the /checkout page, but inside the checkout page they can't sign out and I don't know why.
How can I fix or work around this?
